# ¿Como puedo actualizar un campo de la tabla, luego de que pasen 15 días de insertado?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente tabla , quiero saber, como puedo hacer, que cuando inserte una nueva columna, y que el estado sea Reposando, al pasar 15 días , se actualice a 'Listo'

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se me ocurre que trabajes con [eventos](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-event.html) en MySQL y añadas una columna en la tabla para saber la fecha del registro.

```sql
alter table tuTabla add FechaRegistro datetime
```

```sql
+----+----------+-----------+---------------------+
| ID | Estado   | Hectareas | FechaRegistro       |
+----+----------+-----------+---------------------+
| 1  | Listo    | 223       | 2022-11-05 08:26:00 |
| 2  | Listo    | 1123      | 2022-11-05 16:45:78 |
+----+----------+-----------+---------------------+
```

Una vez teniendo esto podrás realizar tu evento y, en caso no sea una base de datos con muchos registros, podrías hacerlo cada hora y que 'barra' con todos los registros para saber si ya pasarons sus 15 días.

```sql
delimiter |

CREATE EVENT eventito
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 1 HOUR
    COMMENT 'Conocer si pasaron los 15 días'
    DO
      BEGIN
        UPDATE tuTabla
        set Estado = 'Listo'
        where DATEDIFF(now(), FechaRegistro) = 15;
      END |

delimiter ;
```

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, lo implementé y me sirvió !